# using array_length inside a WHERE statement in ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I am more comfortable with activerecord as opposed to vanilla SQL so i'm having a bit of trouble.

I have a Relationships table with a property called sequence which is of type array. The array is either empty or contains a series of numbers.

What I am trying to achieve is to write an AR scope the allows me to return only records whose size of their sequence array is equal to `num` . I imagine it looking something like this:

```
def self.of_order(num)
   where("array_length(sequence, 1) = ?", num)
end
```

If it were available in active record, I would imagine it looking like:

```
def self.of_order(num)
   where(sequence.size == num)
end
```

EDIT: 
Here's what the migration looks like:

```
class CreateRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :relationships do |t|
      t.integer :root_id
      t.integer :destination_id
      t.boolean :first_order?
      t.text :sequence, array: true, default: []

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Sample data:

```
[
    [ 0] #<Relationship:0x007f8d5a5c82c8> {
                    :id => 73,
               :root_id => 51,
             :target_id => 52,
          :first_order? => true,
              :sequence => [],
            :created_at => Thu, 20 Oct 2016 19:05:22 UTC +00:00,
            :updated_at => Thu, 20 Oct 2016 19:05:22 UTC +00:00,
        :primitive_type => "spouse"
    },
    [ 1] #<Relationship:0x007f8d5a5c8188> {
                    :id => 74,
               :root_id => 52,
             :target_id => 51,
          :first_order? => true,
              :sequence => [22,43,90],
            :created_at => Thu, 20 Oct 2016 19:05:22 UTC +00:00,
            :updated_at => Thu, 20 Oct 2016 19:05:22 UTC +00:00,
        :primitive_type => "spouse"
    }
]
```

I'd want `Relationship.all` to return both records,
`Relationship.of_order(0)` to return the 1st record,
`Relationship.of_order(3)` to return the 2nd record,
and `Relationship.of_order(2)` to return none.

Comment: show more details about your model and migrations and some sample data ...

Comment: @johnnynemonic added

Comment: @muistooshort That produces `SELECT "relationships".* FROM "relationships" WHERE (array_length(sequence, 1) = 0)` and comes back empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the root of your problem is that `array_length` is `null` when the array is empty:

```
=> select array_length(array[]::text[], 1);
 array_length 
--------------

(1 row)

=> select coalesce(array_length(array[]::text[], 1), 0);
 coalesce 
----------
        0
(1 row)
```

This isn't exactly clearly documented so don't feel bad if you missed it.

So given:

```
def self.of_order(num)
  where("array_length(sequence, 1) = ?", num)
end
```

`Relationship.of_order(6)` will work just fine but `Relationship.of_order(0)` will end up trying to do `null = 0` inside the database and that is never true so you don't find your empty arrays.

Two easy solutions come to mind:

1. You can handle the `of_order(0)` case explicitly in your scope:

   ```
   def self.of_order(num)
     if(num == 0)
       where('array_length(sequence, 1) is null')
     else
       where('array_length(sequence, 1) = ?', num)
     end
   end
   ```
2. Throw a `coalesce` call into the query to convert NULLs to zeros and let the database worry about it:

   ```
   def self.of_order(num)
     where('coalesce(array_length(sequence, 1), 0) = ?', num)
   end
   ```

Comment: Hero! saved me a headache